# Spring-boot OncePerRequestFilter - Missing request params after caching the request

Tags: java, spring-boot, filter, oauth

Using SpringBoot OAuth security.

I have written a RequestWrapper to read the request body before calling the `filterChain.doFilter()` following the https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reading-httpservletrequest-multiple-times.

I get the  `InvalidRequestException, Missing grant type` if I wrap the `httpServletRequest`. I also noticed that I get the error even if I don't read the request body in my filter. Just wrapping it leads to this error.

When I debugged further, requestParameters map is empty in

`public TokenRequest createTokenRequest(Map<String, String> requestParameters, ClientDetails authenticatedClient)`

What method have I missed overriding, that makes the `requestParameters` empty when wrapped?

I send the request as below:

[image]